# Contacting a job poster on linkedin to ask for clarifications before applying?

Tags: professionalism, linkedin

I'm a graduate with some years of occasional programming experience (no professional experience besides an internship). The company in question is looking for an entry level developer and does not specify how many years of experience the position requires (although I believe entry level is 0 - 3 years). I have some of those skills but all (to further clarify this is not an ad that require knowledge of most languages and frameworks like some are). Since I don't really know if I'm qualified, can I email the poster asking if I can apply for said position given my skills and position? I'm not sure what the correct etiquette is here with linkedin.

Comment: Generally speaking a job posting just lists all the relevant skills but the job poster knows that a applicant probably doesn't have ALL the skills listed and would be expected to learn a few here and there. With that said, it never hurts to apply. There are no cons to applying to a position. My recommendation is not to read the description too much. Just do a blanket apply using keywords and see which ones ping you back.

Answer (score 7):

The correct etiquette here is to apply for the job if it seems of interest to you and if you feel you fit the description or *nearly* fit the description.

Your skills and your experience should be visible on your CV. If the hiring responsible find them a good fit for the job, you'll receive an answer. They'll ask further question if needed before considering you.

In all case, sending a CV sounds more assertive (because you know you could do the job) than asking :) Sounding assertive is good when looking for a job.

Keep in mind: they're paid to browse through CVs. You're not paid at all, so you have nothing to loose in applying.

Comment: The job was posted by one of the developers. I asked because I don't feel comfortable spamming my CV if they consider a hard requirement everything in the description. The job description is short and well-written, so they obviously took the time and not just write a generic one. I certainly wouldn't like everyone to apply if those were hard requirements and would instead appreciate a message prior. But again, this is just me and often times I don't know what I'm talking about :P

Comment: Yeah; well look at it this way: you want a job, so you'll apply. The recruiter's job is to find an employee, and it implies receiving and sorting the CVs. So don't worry to send a CV if you feel you could do the job. But of course, asking first _could_ help create a first contact and increase your chances, but not necessarily.

Comment: @user50177 If you e-mail the recruiter first to point out what you *don't* have from their wish list, this may unintentionally create the wrong impression. Your CV should highlight your "selling points" i.e. your positives; your actual skills. Let them decide based on those.

Comment: Good point @Brandin, I'll just have to either apply or not.

Answer (score 3):

If you think you could be a good fit for the position, then apply.  Asking if you should apply, which is essentially a roundabout way of applying, will make you look unprofessional. If you don't think you'd be a good fit, why would the employer?